# Smartface 4.5 IOS publish Node.js compability

Tags: smartface.io

I am trying to publish with new version smartface 4.5 ios app but it gives an error "Your Node.js (0.10.35) is not compatible with Smartface app studio. Please check your configuration and try again" error. Which version of Node.js has to be used? Also during installation it installed Node.js need to install manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by replacing https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.4.1/   ..

Comment: Unistall Node.js and install again with new version the link i gave!

Answer (score 0):

Smartface supports 0.12 as min version of nodejs. I'm using 5.4.1, you can use any version higher than or equal to 0.12.